# No connection is available to service this operation: ZRANGEBYSCORE redis

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis

i'm getting this error always

asp.net core 2.0

StackExchange.Redis.StrongName 1.2.6

3 redis server 1 master 2 replica

reading from replica only and writing to master

initializing connection manager like this

```
 public  static class X
    {
        static string connectionString;

        public static void InitializeConnectionString(string cnxString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cnxString))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cnxString));

            connectionString = cnxString;
        }

        private static readonly Lazy LazyConnection = new Lazy(() =>
        {
            var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
            connection.PreserveAsyncOrder = false;
            return connection;

        });

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer SafeCoonect
        {
            get
            {
                return LazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }
      }
```

[image]

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is
>   available to service this operation: ZRANGEBYSCORE
>   xxxxx:day20171122:xxxx; It was not possible to connect to the redis
>   server(s); ConnectTimeout ---> System.AggregateException: One or more
>   errors occurred. (It was not possible to connect to the redis
>   server(s); ConnectTimeout) (It was not possible to connect to the
>   redis server(s); ConnectTimeout) (It was not possible to connect to
>   the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout) (It was not possible to connect
>   to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout) --->
>   StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to
>   connect to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed[T](TaskCompletionSource`1
>   source, Exception unthrownException) in
>   x:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line
>   2000 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at y.d__12.MoveNext() in x:\x.cs:line 163 --- End of stack trace
>   from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at y.d__8.MoveNext() in x:\x.cs:line 70 --- End of stack trace
>   from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at z.d__14.MoveNext() in z:\z\z.cs:line 113 --- End of stack
>   trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at lambda_method(Closure , Object ) at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext() ---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.d__9.MoveNext() --- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.d__9.MoveNext() --- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

Comment: is this console application or web application? How are you setting up connection string?

Comment: it's a web app and x class above is for setting connection string and abortconnect is false

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old, but in case others run into it.
Github issues, list this as fixed in version 2.X

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/871

871 also lists the above stackexchange question 
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/743